# Mac OSX Flash/Flixel Development Xcode

Tags: xcode, flash, vmware, flixel

I would like to get started developing games with Flixel, but im on a mac. I have Xcode Installed since i also develop Iphone Apps and i saw an article on setting up a template for Mac development https://github.com/AdamAtomic/flixel/wiki/xcode-basic-setup I have tried to do this but it does not seem to work (maybe its out of date?) does any ideas on how i could develop on mac osx or should i just use VMWare.

I really want to develop on Mac OSX.

If anyone could recomend me some software(i really need it free cause im a bit short on cash =P) that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flixel is an as3 library, so it would be better to work with a flash development environment. Most flixel developers use such tools, and you'll get much better support and tutorials. The best deal would be using FlashDevelop, a free as3 environment for Windows, but since you prefer using Mac OSX, you might wanna try Flex/Flash Builder.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, I am using xcode on vmware 8.0 and I have just download an ios image and run it on vmware (not installed it) then download xcode 4 and installed it(xcode) in mac. You can do all this set up in just free:p if you have difficulty in finding image than you can tell, I will post the links.